# If else statement planets

Tags: python

so i'm trying to make a program to calculate weight on different planets. It is frustrating because it will not calculate properly.

```
if ("Mercury" or "mercury" == planetName):                        
    weight = weightObject * mercury
elif ("Venus" or "VEnus" == planetName):                       
    weight = weightObject * venus                 
elif ("Earth's Moon" or "Earths Moon" == planetName):                     
     weight = weightObject * earthsmoon
elif ("Mars" or "MArs" or "MARS" == planetName):                       
    weight = weightObject * mars
elif ("Jupiter" or "JUpiter" == planetName):                       
    weight = weightObject * jupiter
elif ("Saturn" or "saturn" == planetName):                       
    weight = weightObject * saturn
elif ("uranus" or "Uranus" == planetName):
    weight = weightObject * uranus
elif ("neptune" or "Neptune" == planetName):
    weight = weightObject * neptune
elif ("pluto" or "Pluto" == planetName):
     weight = weightObject * pluto
else:
    weight = -1

#To print out the planet and weight and make sure its a planet and non   negative number
#It will not calculate a negative weight or different planet than listed

if (weightObject > 0):
print("The weight of the object on",planetName,"is {0:,.2f}".format(weight))
else:
    print("Error: Planet name not found or number was negative. Please try      again.")
```

If I type in 20.5 for each planet it gives me the exact same number for all of them. Can someone please help?

Comment: Can you post full code to test it or a fully functional part if it's too long.

Comment: Can you post all of your code?

Comment: Why don't you use a dictionary to map planet names to the weight factor, instead of all those if statements?

Answer (score 4):

```
if ("Mercury" or "mercury" == planetName):                        
    weight = weightObject * mercury
```

should be

```
if planetName == 'Mercury' or planetName == 'mercury'                        
    weight = weightObject * mercury
```

or more succinctly

```
if planetName in ("Mercury", "mercury"):                        
    weight = weightObject * mercury
```

or even

```
if planetName.lower() == 'mercury'
```

Comment: Do you mean `if planetName.lower() == 'mercury`?  I was just about to add that.

Comment: Erased last comment.  Yes, that is what I meant.

Comment: Thanks a bunch it worked after I put in    (planetName == 'Mercury' or planetName == 'mercury'):

Answer (score 1):

Try`if ("Mercury"==planetName or "mercury"==planetName) ...`

and so on down the line.   It's quite likely that your first statement is executing due to `if ("Mecury")` evaluating to `true`.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
if(planetName in ["Mercury", "mercury"])
```

or simpler:

```
planetName.lower() == "mercury"
```

Also, it would be a good idea for you to open up a python interpreter and start typing things like:

```
bool("Mercury")
"Mercury" == "mercury"
"Mercury" and "mercury" == "Mercury"
"Mercury" or "mercury" == "Mercury"
bool(None)
bool(True)
bool(False)
bool([])
bool({})
bool([1])
bool({"a":"a"})
```

Get to know what evaluates to true in python and what evaluates to false. It will make your life easier :D

Or another cool trick put the values your multiplying by in a dictionary.

```
weights = {"mercury": mercury, "venus": venus, "Earth's Moon": earthsmoon, "Earths Moon": earthsmoon .... etc.}
try:
    weight = weights[planetName.lower()] * weightObject
except KeyError:
    weight = -1

if weight > 0:
    .......
```

Comment: If I could upvote you again for your edit, I would. :)

Answer (score 0):

Statements like `"Mercury" or "mercury" == planetName` won't do what you want.

You will have to write them separately like `("Mercury" == planetName) or ("mercury" == planetName)`

Using a dictionary to get the factors from the name may be a good alternative.